# json string casting issue

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

> data[i]['title']=
>   {varent_pos: 1, varent_ct: 0, title: Aashirvaad Atta with Multigrains
>   pouch, imageslist: [], varent_id: null, id: 43469930505}

```
                    try {
                      final parsed = json.decode(data[i]['title']);

                    } on FormatException catch (e) {
                      print("That string didn't look like Json.");
                    } on NoSuchMethodError catch (e) {
                      print('That string was null!');
                    }"
```

But it is showing "That string didn't look like Json"

```
print(data[i]['title']);
```

> {varent_pos: 1, varent_ct: 0, title: Aashirvaad Atta with Multigrains
>   pouch, imageslist: [], varent_id: null, id: 43469930505}

Answer (score 0):

First try printing the content of **data[i]['title']** just to make sure it's a String and seems valid.

After that you can try running the JSON through https://jsonlint.com/ that linter.

And last but not list try printing the actual exception in the catch statement, maybe it carries more information that could be useful.

Comment: I see, in fact the content of **data[i]['title']** is not a string it's a **Map<String, dynamic>** already. You don't have to decode it, it's decoded.